# Xamarin Forms iOS not debugging after deploying to phyical device

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-debugging

So for months now I have been struggling to debug after deploying from my Visual Studio (PC) to my mac server (Mac Mini M1). The application completely builds and begins the deployment process by loading assemblies while the splash page displays on the physical device. After the last assembly loads the debugger terminates with no reported errors. see below:

```
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/AutoMapper.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/[appName].Interfaces.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/GraphQL.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/GraphQL.Client.Abstractions.Websocket.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/GraphQL.Client.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/GraphQL.Client.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].app/GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F79FD8-A3A6-441D-B0F5-7CDC3EF52807/[appName].iOS.app/[appName].Application.dll
The app has been terminated.
```

I have attempted to lower my Xamarin.IOS version, my Xcode to 14.2, my visual studio 2022 to previous versions. I have changed my linker behavior, removed hot restart/reload, and played with settings throughout both computers to no avail. Still unable to debug anything on iOS devices.

It deploys fine to an emulator but because of the app's need for a Bluetooth connection, I need a physical device. My physical device is an iPhone 11 on iOS 16.4

Comment: Microsoft seems to have trouble keeping up with Apple changes that affect such testing from PC. For iOS testing, I find it easier to attach device to Mac mini, and build/run in VS Mac. The Mac desktop can be controlled from PC desktop (search for ways to do this), but for me that was laggy, so I hooked a second monitor and keyboard and mouse to my Mac Mini.

Comment: The answer for me was just to put my mac mini on ethernet instead of debugging over wifi *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to debug over wifi and once I put my Mac on ethernet, I had no problems with my debugger. Seems super obvious now but hopefully if anyone else runs into this issue, they can avoid months of torment like I did :)

Comment: Good catch! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.